# How to set a property on all instances of an Emberjs View class

Tags: ember.js

I have a view class called `App.BlockView`. It has a property called `selected` and clicking on this view toggles the `selected` property.

When I capture certain events such as clicking on the background of the container, I want to set `selected` property to false on all the views (or those which have it set to true). Is there any way in ember to collect all instances of a view class -- regardless of where and how they are instantiated -- and set a property on them?

Note that my views are created in handlebars template like `{{View App.BlockView}}` and therefore I don't keep a reference to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have views register and unregister themselves on the class to accomplish this. e.g.

```
App.BlockView.reopenClass({
  blockViews: [],
  deselectAll: function() {
    this.blockViews.forEach(function(blockView) {
      blockView.set('selected', false);
    });
  }
});

App.BlockView.reopen({
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    App.BlockView.blockViews.pushObject(this);
  },
  destroy: function() {
    App.BlockView.blockViews.removeObject(this);
    this._super();
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you give an example of how you would trigger the deselectAll() function ? I guess from the controller you could do App.BlockView.deselectAll(), but it seems bad for to use this static way.

Comment: For some reason I was expecting that Ember would keep a reference to all my views and make them available. But this solution is easy to implement and works perfectly fine. Thank you Luke!

Comment: @sly7_7, you're right. It's a bit of a smell to use the class (since it is a global). Off the top of my head, you could register the view instances on some sort of injected registry, which is also injected into your controller or wherever you need to trigger the action that is to affect all the instances.